# android:how to get tag from html

Tags: android, html, tags

I'm trying to get specific tag from one web site.
I can read the HTML but can't get the specific tag.
Is there any way to do this task?
I was searching in other threads but I could not find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://zodia.bg/sign/aries");

}

  private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpGet httpGet = null;
        HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
        String s = "";

        try {
            if(mHttpClient == null){
                mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            }


            httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


            response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
            s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return s;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){


           text.setText(result);



    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a DOM traversal with something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) or you can manually use String manipulation to find what you need and parse it out (`substring()` and `indexOf()`, etc.)